# Visual studio 2022 doesn't complie because of this

Tags: c, visual-studio, compiler-errors

In visual studio 2022 I can't compile this little program and on Clion, visual studio code and others it compiles.

[image: Img of the code inside visual studio]

I don't know if it could be a problem of the clang compiler or some configuration of visual studio (but stills on default).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    //Variable declarations
    int size;

    printf("INPUT\n");
    printf("SIZE (2-3)?\n");
    scanf("%d", &size);

    int t[size][size]; //This is marked as wrong (only in visual studio 2022 not other IDE's)

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    //matrix read
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            printf("POSITION(%d, %d)?\n", i, j);

            scanf("%d", &t[i][j]);
        }
    }
    int calc = 0;
    //calc matrix
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            calc = calc + t[i][j];
        }
    }
    printf("suma: %d", calc);
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for reading.

I've tested the code on other IDE's and compiles without problems.

Comment: Microsoft's C compiler does not work as other compilers. You might want to research on "VLA" (variable length arrays).

Comment: If you know the maximum size and can limit the input to that, you can use a fixed array size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a Variable Length Array, a pointer to pointer, `int **t`, could be used.
Allocate the pointers and then for each pointer, allocate the elements.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    //Variable declarations
    int size;

    printf("INPUT\n");
    printf("SIZE (2-3)?\n");
    if ( 1 != scanf("%d", &size)) {
        fprintf ( stderr, "Could not scan an integer\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int **t = NULL; // pointer to pointer
    
    if ( NULL == ( t = malloc ( size * sizeof *t))) {
        fprintf ( stderr, "Could not allocate pointers\n");
        return 1;
    }
    int each = 0;
    for ( each = 0; each < size; ++each) {
        if ( NULL == ( t[each] = malloc ( size * sizeof **t))) {
            fprintf ( stderr, "Could not allocate elements\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    //matrix read
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            printf("POSITION(%d, %d)?\n", i, j);

            if ( 1 != scanf("%d", &t[i][j])) {
                fprintf ( stderr, "Could not scan an integer\n");
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
    int calc = 0;
    //calc matrix
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            calc = calc + t[i][j];
        }
    }
    printf("suma: %d\n", calc);

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        free ( t[i]);
    }
    free ( t);
    return 0;
}
```